# How to check if any Merge request has been merged in a repo in Gitlab in last 60 minutes?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I want to trigger a pipeline based on a condition.  The pipepline should be created only if there is one or more merge requests merged in last 60 minutes in the repository.

Is there a way to find this out ?
I checked merge requests API but didn't find anything specific - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitLab API in combination with a script or automation tool. While the Merge Requests API itself might not provide a direct way to check for merged requests within the last 60 minutes, you can achieve this by using the `created_at` and `merged_at` fields provided by the API.

Here's a general outline of how you can approach this:

1. Use the "List Merge Requests" API endpoint to fetch a list of merge requests in the repository.
2. For each merge request in the list, check the `merged_at` field. If it falls within the last 60 minutes, increment a counter.
3. After iterating through all merge requests, if the counter is greater than zero, trigger your pipeline.

Here's a simplified example using Python and the `requests` library:

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

repository_id = "your_repository_id"
personal_access_token = "your_personal_access_token"
api_url = f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{repository_id}/merge_requests"

response = requests.get(api_url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": personal_access_token})
merge_requests = response.json()

current_time = datetime.now()
recent_merge_count = 0

for mr in merge_requests:
    if "merged_at" in mr and mr["merged_at"]:
        merged_at = datetime.strptime(mr["merged_at"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
        time_difference = current_time - merged_at
        if time_difference <= timedelta(minutes=60):
            recent_merge_count += 1

if recent_merge_count > 0:
    # Trigger your pipeline here
    print("Triggering pipeline...")
else:
    print("No recent merged merge requests.")
```

Please note that you need to replace `"your_repository_id"` and `"your_personal_access_token"` with your actual repository ID and GitLab personal access token.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gitlab Api as below

```
curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/merge_requests?state=<state>&private_token=<project/group token>&created_after=<timestamp in ISO 8601 format>"
```

Docs Link :
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests